# Trying to Setup Spark to Run in Jupyter Notebook. Code Runs but Nothing Happens

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to setup Spark to run on my ThinkPad laptop. I followed the instructions listed in the link below.

https://medium.com/@ansabiqbal/setting-up-apache-spark-pyspark-on-windows-11-machine-e16b7382624a

My System Properties looks like this.

[image]

So, you can see my Hadoop_Home, Java_Home, Spark_Home, and Path values. I think these are al correct, unless I missed something here.

Now, I got to my Anaconda Prompt and entered 'pip install findspark' and then I entered 'pyspark' in the same Command Prompt.

I also edited the 'bashrc.sh' file, and added four lines at the bottom of the file:
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'

Then, I saved the change and closed the file. Now, I start Jupyter Notebook and enter the following code.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SampleDataExample").getOrCreate()

folder_path = "C:\\Users\\ryan_\\Desktop\\Coding\\Python\\CSV Merge All Files into One File\\multiple_text_files\\*.txt"
df = spark.read.text(folder_path).withColumn("filename", input_file_name())

df.show()
```

That runs for several minutes, but nothing really happens, so I canceled the job and restarted the Kernel. I feel like this job should finish in a few seconds. I feel like something is not setup correctly, or configured or correctly, or whatever. Has anyone here experienced this behavior? Does anyone have a solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my machine and restarting the Kernel, I got this code below to work.

```
# Read a single CSV file into a dataframe

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ReadCSV").getOrCreate()

# Path to the CSV file
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Book1.csv'

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()
```

Also, got this code below to work, so I think I'm all set now.

```
# Merge multiple CSV files in a folder into a single Dataframe

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import os

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MergeCSVFiles").getOrCreate()

# Path to the folder containing CSV files
folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\CSV\\'

# List all CSV files in the folder
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

# Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the merged data
merged_df = None

# Loop through each CSV file and merge into the DataFrame
for file_name in csv_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
    
    # Read the CSV file into a DataFrame
    df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
    
    # Add a new column with the input file name
    df = df.withColumn("file_name", lit(file_name))
    
    # Union the DataFrame with the merged DataFrame
    if merged_df is None:
        merged_df = df
    else:
        merged_df = merged_df.union(df)

# Show the merged DataFrame
merged_df.show()
```